# Finding results from and between groups of parentheses with regexp

Tags: regex

Text format:

```
(Superships)    
Eirik Raude - olajkutató fúrósziget
(Eirik Raude - Oil Patch Explorer)
```

1. I need regex to match text beetween first set of parentheses. Results: text1.
2. I need regex to match text beetween first set of parentheses and second set of parentheses. Results: text2.
3. I need regex to match text beetween second set of parentheses. Results: text3.

   - text1: Superships, represent english title,
   - text2: Eirik Raude - olajkutató fúrósziget, represent hungarian subtitle,
   - text3: Eirik Raude - Oil Patch Explorer, represent english subtitle.

I need regex for perl script to match this title and subtitle. Example script:

```
($anchor) = $tree->look_down(_tag=>"h1", class=>"blackbigtitle"); 
if ($anchor) { 
    $elem = $anchor;  
    my ($engtitle, $engsubtitle,  $hunsubtitle @tmp); 
    while (($elem = $elem->right()) && 
            ((ref $elem) && ($elem->tag() ne "table"))) { 
        @tmp = get_all_text($elem); 
        push @lines, @tmp; 
        $line = join(' ', @tmp); 
        if (($engtitle) = $line =~ m/**regex need that return text1**/) { 
            push @{$prog->{q(title)}}, [$engtitle, 'en']; 
            t "english-title added: $engtitle"; 
        } 
        elsif (($engsubtitle) = $line =~ m/**regex need that return text3**/) { 
            push @{$prog->{q(sub-title)}}, [$subtitle, 'en']; 
            t "english_subtitle added: $engsubtitle"; 
        } 
        elsif (($hunsubtitle) = $line =~ m/**regex need that return text2**/) { 
            push @{$prog->{q(hun-subtitle)}}, [$hunsubtitle, 'hu']; 
            t "hungarinan_subtitle added: $hunsubtitle"; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you after a regex to match all three in one go, or one to match any one of those?

Comment: Did you read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Comment: I need regex to match separately each text from line.

Comment: I need one regex to match text1 if line format contains first set parentheses, I need one regex to match text2 if line not contains parentheses, I need one regex to match text3 if line contains second set of parentheses (before this line there is another line that contains parentheses, ).

Comment: I tried something for the first line but returns text1 and text3. I need only text1.         ^\s*\(([^\)]+)\)\s*$

Comment: Are text1, text2 and text3 compose by any character but `()`?

Comment: text1 - represent english title, text2 - represent english subtitle, text3 represent hunarian title. I need regex for perl script to match this title and subtitle. Example script: if (($english-title) = $line =~ m/regex/) , elsif (($english-subtitle) = $line =~ m/regex/), elsif (($hungarian-title) = $line =~ m/regex/)

Comment: We're not here to do work for you. What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: @user: How can the english-title be distinguished from hungarian-title?

Comment: Are you sure regex is the best tool for this job?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment, you can do something like :

```
if (($english_title) = $line =~ m/^\(([^)]+)\)$/)  {
    $found_english_title = 1;
    # do stuff
} elsif (($english-subtitle) = $line =~ m/^([^()]+)$/) {
    # do stuff
} elsif ($found_english_title && ($hungarian-title) = $line =~ m/^\(([^)]+)\)$/) {
    # do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to match them all in one expression:

```
\(([^)]+)\)([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)
```

This matches (, then anything that's not ), then ), then anything that's not (, then, (, ... I think you get the picture.

First group will be text1, second group will be text2, third group will be text3.

You can also just make a more generix regex that matches something like "(text1)", "(text1)text2(text3)" or "text1(text2)" when applied several times:

```
(?:^|[()])([^()])(?:[()]|$)
```

This matches the beginning of the string or ( or ), then characters that are not ( or ), then ( or ) or the end of the string. :? is for non-capturing group, so the first group will have the string. Something more complex is necessary to match ( with ) every time, i.e., it can match "(text1(".

Comment: -1, this has errors in the regex and must be untested. Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\(( <-- HERE [^)]+\)([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)/

Comment: No, I need regex to match separately each text from line.

Comment: @Moritz yes it's untested, but you didnt copy it right, it should be m/\(([^)]+\)([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)/, you're missing the first backslash.

Comment: hmm I see that something is eating up the extra backslashes in the comments section.....

Comment: right... your regex lacks a ')' behind the 8th character (this plus sign)  I think. -- Thes for comments section: One backslash: \ Two backslashes: \\ three: \\\ 4: \\\\ 5: \\\\\

Comment: I need 3 regex to match only text1 or text2 or text3